# Checking if the function is onto

Tags: functions

Consider a function $f$ defined over $R \to R$

$y=x^2+2x$

Well it's inverse comes out to be

$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt {x+1} -1$

Well, this seems to be undefined for all values of co-domain $\lt -1$

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Comment: If your reasoning concludes "Therefore this function is NOT 'onto'" then, yes, you are correct.  You could also do this problem by 'completing the square':  $y= x^2+ 2x= x^2+ 2x+ 1- 1= (x+ 1)^2- 1$.  When x= -1, y= -1.   For any x other than -1, $(x+ 1)^2$ is larger than 0 so y is larger than -1.  There is no x such that y is, say, -2 so this function is NOT 'onto'.

Answer (score 2):

We have $f (x)=(x+1)^2-1 \ge -1$ for all $x $. Hence $f (\mathbb R)=[-1, \infty) $.

Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

If the function is onto, one would expect a reverse for any value.  Otherwise, it would be into.